# How can i merge my "Fix branch" back to "Master branch" from Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

I have created an application in Android Studio and i have integrated it with Git. So far i commit & push my changes to the master branch.

Now i have created a new branch (from master) named "Fix1" and i have committed and pushed my latest changes to this branch. Which are the next steps in order to merge Fix1 back to Master? Can i do it from Android studio?

This is what i see as options at the bottom right git menu:
[image: Git options in Android Studio]

Comment: You may want to clean up the topic of your question a bit.  Reading it I thought the question was about branching philosophy and was going to vote to close it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. First you need to push your code in in your fix1 branch which you already did
2. Than change your branch to master
3. Now from top VCS control go to git->pull and select your fix1 branch and than click on pull button

Now it will merge your fix1 code to master branch

Comment: from these options how do i change branch back to master?

Comment: Just click on `moh/master` and click on force checkout than in below section you will see `git:master`

Answer (score 10):

In your case simply move back to master branch go back to branches list - press fix1 branch and press "merge into current" - this will merge fix1 into master.

A more general explanation:

First of all, make sure you have committed your changes before the merge.

Let's say you have a branch called A and branch called B and you want to merge B into A, so this is what you need to do:

1. Make sure you are on branch A, you can see it displayed by pressing right click on your project --> Git -- > Repository --> branches. The current branch name will appear at the bottom of the branches list(Or at the top of the list marked with yellow from the latest Android studio version
   )
2. from this branches list pick the branch you want to merge into the current branch and pick "Merge" in this case pick branch B and press merge
3. If no conflicts are there - you are done. If there are conflicts then you need to resolve them - android has a nice merging tool - however, you can do it easily yourself - the conflicted files will be colored in red - you will see the conflicts areas with both branches - remove the undesired code - after resolving all the conflicts you need to press CTRL+A to add them to the git - and then commit your branch again --> Done.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps

Step 1 - Commit and push your code with repository "fix1"

Step 2 - Change your branch from "fix1" to master by checking out .

Step 3 - Now pull the request and choose "fix1" to pull request into master repositories.